# WPF and EF 4 validation

Tags: wpf, validation, entity-framework-4

I have chosen EF4 as the ORM for our wpf project and currently looking at different validation possibilities. Currently i'm gearing towards implementation of IDataErrorInfo  (http://www.arrangeactassert.com/using-idataerrorinfo-for-validation-in-mvvm-with-silverlight-and-wpf/) in my ViewModel. What i'm currently missing when implementing a null validation is the ability to check the EdmScalarPropertyAttribute for the IsNullable flag. Any suggestion? And is this the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

Check our Beth Massi's blog

[Implementing Validation in WPF on Entity Framework Entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2009/07/07/implementing-validation-in-wpf-on-entity-framework-entities.aspx)
(article with VB code)

[How Do I: Hook Up and Display Validation in WPF using Entity Framework?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee364700.aspx)
(video with VB and C# code)